# roscpp relative vs global parameter (tutorial)

Tags: ros, parameter, roscpp, getparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I thought I understood the concept of global and relative. But apparently while doing the tutorial

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
std::string global_name, relative_name, default_param;
if (nh.getParam("/global_name", global_name))
{
  ...
}
  
 if (nh.getParam("relative_name", relative_name))
{
 ... 
}
```

I expect that if my global name is /bla and my param is /bla/param1. I could simply use the second if loop with getParam("param1",relative_name), But this doesn't work.

[here is the solution which requires you to instantiate a private node handle.](http://answers.ros.org/question/11098/roscpp-relative-parameter/)

My question now is what does the tutorial mean then by relative name ? and relative to what ? because it doesn't work relative to my node name.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242917/roscpp-relative-vs-global-parameter-(tutorial)/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what tutorial you are referring to, but relative names are relative to ROS namespaces, i.e., if the node has been pushed into a namespace /bla. For parameters that are in the namespace of a node, using a private node handle is the right way to go.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-09-05**:
I still didn't understand sorry. Could you explain it with example names maybe. It would be a big big help
[Here is the link to the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Getting_Parameters)

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-09-05**:
I have also tried to look at [this link on resolving names but they all look the same.](http://wiki.ros.org/Names#Resolving) In this example /wg/node3/foo/bar where wg is the namespace could you explain what is relative name ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-09-05**:
If your node is named `foo` and pushed in a namespace `bar`, the parameter '/baz' (global) should resolve to '/baz'. The parameter 'baz' (relative) should resolve to '/bar/baz' and the lookup for 'baz' in a private nh should give '/bar/foo/baz'.